# Omit folder and few scripts in mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following problem. My .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /phpuserarea/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^mod/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]


ErrorDocument 404 /phpuserarea/404/index.php
```

But whenever I try to directly access anything in the `mod` directory the server responds with 404.

Other problem is, that besides the index.php I want to allow direct access to let's say testa.php and testb.php

Those are my ajax files and I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /phpuserarea/404/index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /phpuserarea/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mod/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You need leading slash in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` and better not use anchor `^` as your .htaccess is inside `/phpuserarea/`.

Also you don't need to use `?%{QUERY_STRING}` in target since query string is automatically passed over to target if your rule doesn't overwrite it.